smooth transition in blend tree for walking animation on unity
I created walking animations with an animator in Unity using a blend tree. The animation is based on two parameters (horizontal and vertical axis).
When horizontal and vertical =0, the animation change from walk to idle position.
When there is a passage from 0 tò 1/-1 in h/v axis the animation work buy of the passage Is from 1 to -1 or -1 to 1 the animation is not smooth and changes instantly, as if there is a cut between the two animations.
I tried putting idle position in blend tree of the walk animation (h and v axis = 0), but the situation seems ridiculous, as if it were a foreign frame.
the animations are bought and should not give this defect. Is there a way to make the walk transition from forward tò backward and from right tò left smoothly...?

Could you [edit] your question to include the code that handles the smoothing that you already tried?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
